# Example of measure that is discontinuous at $\emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$\newcommand{\p}{\mathbb{P}}$
$\newcommand{\tsum}{\textstyle{\sum}}$
$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}$
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$

**Problem**

Give an example showing that, in general, a measure that can take
the value $+\infty$ could be countably additive, but still not continuous
at "the zero" $\emptyset.$

**Attempt**
Let our measure space be $\left\{ \R,\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)\right\} $,
define $\mu$ by $$\mu(A)=
\begin{cases}
\infty & \mbox{if }A\mbox{ is uncountable}\\
0 & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
then we have $\mu\left(\emptyset\right)=\mu(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(0,\frac{1}{n})=0$.
However, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu((0,\frac{1}{n}))=\infty.$
Therefore, $\mu$ is not continuous.

Comment: How did you define continuity of a measure?

Comment: Your $\mu$ violates monotonicity. A small modification is required.

Comment: @aexl I think it is usual definition continuity. But the object at interest here is set. So if we take a sequence of set $A_n$ decreasing to $\emptyset$, we should have by continuity $\mu(\lim A_n)=\lim\mu(A_n)$

Comment: @DanielFischer Hi Daniel, i have modified my $\mu$. Is it correct now?

Comment: Yes, that works. (Unless we reject the axiom of choice, then it could be that some uncountable set is a countable union of countable sets and your new $\mu$ would not be $\sigma$-additive. If you replace "uncountable" with "non-empty", it works even then.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks!